# Successfully built cardano-node 1.35.7 but still getting version cardano-node and cardano-cli 1.35.3

Tags: cardano-node

I followed the [iohk instructions](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node) to update my cardano-node to version 1.35.7. It built the node with no errors. However when I run `cardano-node --version`, `cardano-cli --version`, I get 1.35.3.

I've checked that my config, topology, etc files are correct. No clue what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your link to the "iohk instructions" links to the git repo, so I am not really sure which instructions you are talking about.

Assuming you are on Linux, you can run the command `which cardano-node` and `which cardano-cli` to figure out where these programs are installed/located. My suspicion is that they are installed in different locations.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually did not completely follow instructions. I missed this step which @Nic_T2H pointed out. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

Building the cardano-node and cardano-cli doesn't mean that your service is using it.

To install the new binaries, copy them from inside the git folder to the folder where the cardano-node.service is looking for binaries to use:

```
sudo cp $(find ./dist-newstyle/build -type f -name "cardano-node") <DestinationPath>/cardano-node
sudo cp $(find ./dist-newstyle/build -type f -name "cardano-cli") <DestinationPath>/cardano-cli
```

than check that the new version is installed:

```
cardano-cli version
cardano-node version
```

Once you are sure about the new version, restart your cardano-node service.

Full documentation about the update procedure: [link](https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node/part-iv-administration/upgrading-a-node)

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly it. I assumed incorrectly and did not do this step. All fixed now!